# Helper's scope (when getting via Mage::helper())

Tags: magento-1.9, helper, scope, http-request, singleton

I'm trying to understand couple of things about helper classes scope and lifetime. I think I got it but it's critical for me to be sure.

So can you please tell me if I'm right about the following assumptions about helper's scope?

1. a helper is a singleton by default (eg when calling `Mage::helper()` it's the same as calling `getSingleton()`).
2. a singleton only live in the scope of the **http request**, eg next http request will no longer have those singletons. same rule applies to helpers.
3. it's possible to use session storage for a helper, which will make the helper instance live through the entire user session, but by default it's **not** session based.
4. calling the same helper from different modules (while handling the same request) will return the same instance. eg a helper singleton instance can be used to transfer data between modules? (I'm not asking if it's the right way, just if its possible :))
5. calling the same helper from **different events** that are triggered from the same http request will return the same helper instance.
6. calling helper from cron job callback will always instantiate a new instance (because cron job is equivalent to an http request scope?)

So am I correct about the points above? Can someone confirm it? I did some testing and found some info here and there, but I want to make sure it's the expected defined behavior, and not just random behavior that might change between versions and systems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The helper will only live during the execution, so #2 is true, it will not persist after the request.

#3, sure you can save any data you want from the Helper into core/session, customer/session, checkout/session etc.
#4, #5, #6 should return the same result no matter what.
Calling the helper from a Model, Controller, even a template file will return the same result.

My only hesitation is on #1.
I am not sure if you can consider it a singleton. I would guess it may depend on what its doing.  Hopefully this helps.

Comment: if you are only unsure about #1 its good enough, as long as you are sure about the other points being valid. I'll wait a little longer to see if no one else think otherwise and accept this answer. thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

Everything you wrote is accurate.

To clarify the singleton behavior: both, Mage::helper() and Mage::getSingleton() look up an entry in the Magento registry (which is a global data storage per request) in the form `_helper/module/class` or `_singleton/module/class` and if it does not exist, instantiate the helper or singleton and store it in the registry.